# Multihop (nested) WireGuard configuration

Tags: vpn, proxy, docker, wireguard

I need to configure 2 different wireguard VPN networks on the same client machine and nest them so that when I make a request it passes through VPN_1 then VPN_2 and then reaches the destination website.
Something similar is described here:
https://mullvad.net/en/help/different-entryexit-node-using-wireguard-and-socks5-proxy/

Currently, I have a working configuration when VPN_1 is configured on a host machine, VPN_2 is configured in a docker container and exposed via socks proxy. If I configure my app to use the socks5 proxy it does the job and I have APP -> VPN_1 -> VPN_2 -> destination. I want to achieve the same goal but in a single docker container (preferably without any socks proxy).

My first idea was to use the same interface and 2 peers (and configure routing via AllowedIPs param so that VPN_1 uses 0.0.0.0/0 and VPN_2 uses <VPN_1 IP>/32) but I have 2 different private keys so probably that's not going to work.
I also tried to have 2 separate interfaces but that doesn't work as well.

Example configs (latest):
VPN_1

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE_KEY_1>
Address = 10.68.187.50/32
MTU = 1280
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wg2 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o wg2 -j MASQUERADE


[Peer]
PublicKey = <PUBLIC_KEY_1>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <VPN_1>:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 120
```

VPN_2

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE_KEY_2>
Address = 172.16.0.2/32
MTU = 1280
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PUBLIC_kEY_2>
AllowedIPs = <VPN_1_IP>/32
Endpoint = <VPN_2>
PersistentKeepalive = 120
```

I also found that some WireGuard clients have this feature out of the box:
https://www.wiresock.net/ (Double VPN (with nested tunnels)).

But with the docker setup, I'm kinda stuck now and would appreciate any help.

UPD `wg-quick` output:

```
/ # wg-quick up vpn1
[#] ip link add vpn1 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf vpn1 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.68.187.50/32 dev vpn1
[#] ip link set mtu 1380 up dev vpn1
[#] wg set vpn1 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev vpn1 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] iptables-restore -n
/ # wg-quick up vpn2
[#] ip link add vpn2 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf vpn2 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 172.16.0.2/32 dev vpn2
[#] ip link set mtu 1440 up dev vpn2
[#] ip -4 route add 193.32.126.70/32 dev vpn2
/ #
/ # curl https://am.i.mullvad.net/connected
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: am.i.mullvad.net
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need two WireGuard interfaces; run them and your app all in the same container or network namespace. Since your app is initiating requests, you don't need to mess around with iptables. And as long as the two VPN endpoints themselves are not behind NAT, you don't need persistent keepalives either.

You *do* need to mess around with your MTU settings, however. Normal Ethernet MTU is 1500 bytes, and WireGuard adds an overhead of 60 bytes for IPv4 packets, so unless you have a more-restrictive link somewhere between you and your two VPN endpoints, your outer WireGuard interface should use a MTU of 1440 (1500 - 60), and your inner WireGuard interface should use a MTU of 1380 (1500 - 60 - 60).

If you do have a MTU restriction somewhere, subtract 60 bytes from the lowest MTU in the path to calculate the MTU for your outer interface, and subtract 60 bytes more for the MTU of your inner interface. See this article's [Calculate the Inner MTU](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/12/wireguard-e2ee-hub-and-spoke/#calculate-the-inner-mtu) section for more details.

Assuming that you have a normal MTU of 1500 through to your VPN endpoints, and that your inner VPN endpoint (VPN 1) is for example 198.51.100.123, use this for your inner WireGuard config:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg-inner.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE_KEY_1>
Address = 10.68.187.50/32
MTU = 1380

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PUBLIC_KEY_1>
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 198.51.100.123:51820
```

And, if your outer VPN endpoint (VPN 2) is for example 203.0.113.234, use this for your outer WireGuard config:

```
# /etc/wireguard/wg-outer.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <PRIVATE_KEY_2>
Address = 172.16.0.2/32
MTU = 1440
FwMark = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = <PUBLIC_KEY_2>
AllowedIPs = 198.51.100.123
Endpoint = 203.0.113.234:51820
```

And if you use `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` for the inner tunnel (like above), be sure to add `FwMark = 51820` to the outer tunnel (like above). This will prevent a loop from the outer tunnel back through the inner tunnel (wg-quick sets up loop protection for the inner tunnel itself using that packet mark -- see this article on [Linux routing and wg-quick](https://ro-che.info/articles/2021-02-27-linux-routing) for more details).

With the inner tunnel to VPN 1 nested inside the outer tunnel to VPN 2, when you connect to say google.com, your connection will work like this:

```
    == outer tunnel ==|
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ inner tunnel ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
You --------------------------------------------------------> Google
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> VPN 1
    ==================> VPN 2
```

VPN 2 will see you as the outer tunnel's source and VPN 1 as the inner tunnel's destination; VPN 1 will see VPN 2 as the inner tunnel's source and Google as the tunneled traffic's destination; and Google will see VPN 1 as the tunneled traffic's source:

```
You ==================> VPN 2 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~> VPN 1 -----> Google
```

Switch the inner and outer tunnels if you want traffic to appear as You => VPN 1 ~> VPN 2 -> Google instead.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. Should I configure it manually rather than with wg-quick? For some reason, it doesn't work when configured with the wg-quick cli.

Comment: I also just added my `wg-quick` output

Comment: If VPN_1 is the "relay" (as @parkee described), it would be the "outer" VPN.

Comment: @parkee: "Could not resolve host" may be a DNS problem; check with `ping -nc1 9.9.9.9`. If it succeeds, try adding `DNS = 9.9.9.9` to your inner config. If it hangs, it's not DNS; instead try running each VPN config by itself with `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` to figure out which config isn't working and fix.

Comment: @tom-yan: Just trying to match the configs posted in the question -- I've updated the answer to explain the ramifications of choosing which VPN to be the inner tunnel and which to be the outer.

Comment: @JustinLudwig
The ping hangs as well. I tried starting VPNs by themselves and both work as expected. The only thing I need to use is DNS with the VPN_1. I'm using `DNS = 1.0.0.1, 1.1.1.1`
Maybe that would shed some light if I mentioned that a VPN_1 is Cloudflare warp and VPN_2 is Mullvad. 

[Interface]
PrivateKey =
Address = 172.16.0.2/32
MTU = 1380
[Peer]
PublicKey =
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 162.159.192.1:2408

[Interface]
PrivateKey =
Address = 10.68.187.50/32
MTU = 1440
DNS = 1.1.1.1
[Peer]
PublicKey =
AllowedIPs = 162.159.192.1
Endpoint = 193.32.126.70:51820

Comment: @parkee: Sorry, I missed a critical piece -- you also need to add `FwMark = 51820` to the outer VPN's config (to stop loops with `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0`). I updated the answer to add it to the example config.

Comment: @JustinLudwig That is not necessary because the prefix length of the route for the outer VPN is 32 (!= 0). The ip rule "magic" wg-quick uses has dealt with that already.

Comment: @parkee Always update your question with the latest confs you tried. Whichever VPN you want the world to see you as (in other words, "what's my ip") should be the inner VPN (i.e. the one that `AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0` should be used in its conf). So far all the description you have given indicates that Mullvad / VPN_2 is the inner one and VPN_1 / the other one is the outer one.

Comment: @parkee If you want to avoid routing traffics for `1.0.0.1` and `1.1.1.1` to  Mullvad / the inner VPN, add them to the `AllowedIPs=` of the outer VPN. (I'm not sure why you would want that though. Mullvad might tell you that "you are not mullvad" / you have DNS leak.)

Comment: @JustinLudwig Thank you, the `FwMark = 51820` actually solved the issue

Comment: @TomYan thanks for the tip. I'm actually still playing around with some settings in scope of the POC but the `FwMark = 51820` actually helped me to finally get it up and running

Comment: Ah my bad, `203.0.113.234` is what need to be "escaped", not `198.51.100.123`.